# ¿Como ordernar un arreglo bidimensional de objetos en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hola quisiera saber como ordenar una array de objetos así

```
{
nomber: "tile",
"x": 100,
"y", "2000"
}
```

necesito ordenarlo primero en Y luego en x

He tratado con el sort pero no me funciono

trate como este

```
array.sort( x = x + 1 > x) pero veo que no funciono
```

Comment: Ordenar las llaves de un objeto??

Comment: Tu pregunta es algo confusa, yo entiendo que deseas ordenar los objetos de tu `Array` usando como discriminador los valores de `y` y luego los valores de `x`. ¿A eso te refieres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debería funcionarte algo así

```js
let datos = [
 {
   nomber: "tile1",
  "x": 100,
  "y": 2000
},
 {
   nomber: "tile2",
  "x": 50,
  "y": 2100
},
   {
   nomber: "tile3",
  "x": 30,
  "y": 2100
},
{
   nomber: "tile4",
  "x": 90,
  "y": 1800
}
]

datos.sort((a,b)=> {
   if(a.y < b.y){
     return -1;
   } else if(a.y > b.y) {
     return 1;
   } else {
     return a.x - b.x;
   }   
})

console.log(datos)
```

Asi ordenas primero los Y de menor a mayor... y en caso de igualdad, los X de menor a mayor

Comment: Podrías hacer el `.sort` más corto con uso de un [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator): `datos.sort((a, b) => a.y < b.y ? -1 : a.y > b.y ? 1 : a.x - b.x)`

Comment: Si... Mas corto, pero menos entendible y mas complicado de debuguear

Answer (score 0):

**Tengo esta función**
La uso para ordenar arrays de objetos a partir de sus hijos

```javascript
function arrayOrderDesc(array = [], childName = "") {
    function compare(a, b) {
      if (typeof a[childName] === "undefined") {
        return 0;
      }
      if (typeof b[childName] === "undefined") {
        return 0;
      }
      if (a[childName] < b[childName]) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a[childName] > b[childName]) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
    return [...array].sort(compare); // clone and sort
  }
function arrayOrderAsc(array = [], childName = "") {
    function compare(a, b) {
      if (typeof a[childName] === "undefined") {
        return 0;
      }
      if (typeof b[childName] === "undefined") {
        return 0;
      }
      if (a[childName] < b[childName]) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a[childName] > b[childName]) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
    return [...array].sort(compare); // clone and sort
  }
```

Luego lo usas asi =

```javascript
arrayOrderAsc(dataArray, "timeStamp"); // <--- ten presente poner el nombre del campo exatamente igual y entre comillas.
```